# get the value of editText inside spinner.onItemSelectedItem

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner

I got a spinner i will load it using a loop and i will also insert it to my database for a default value, after i execute the loop if the user choose an item it will get the selected item to retrieve from my database so in case CursorAnswer is not equal to default value("shananaking") and to "Choose #1" i will then set the Current value of CursorAnswer to my EditText so if its true i will update my boolean gotAnswer to true and break it so if gotAnswer is true i will get the text in my EditText then insert it in my database but the problem is im getting an empty value in my editText, please help!!!

```
public void initSpinner(){
    ArrayList<String> ArrayListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    EditTextAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAnswer);

    final Spinner SpinnerItems = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerItems);
    for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
        ArrayListItems.add(String.valueOf(i));
        if(i == 0){
            mydb.InsertItemsZero(mydb, i, "Choose #1");
        }else mydb.InsertItemsZero(mydb, i, "shananaking");
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> ItemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, ArrayListItems);
    SpinnerItems.setAdapter(ItemAdapter);

    SpinnerItems.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            mGetSpinner = Integer.parseInt(SpinnerItems.getSelectedItem().toString());


            DatabaseHelper mydb = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            Cursor rs = mydb.RetrieveItems(mGetSpinner);
            if (rs.getCount() != 0) {
                rs.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    CursorItemID = rs.getString(0);
                    CursorItems = rs.getString(1);
                    CursorAnswer = rs.getString(2);

                    if (!CursorAnswer.equals("") && !CursorAnswer.equals("shananaking") && !CursorAnswer.equals("Choose #1")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), CursorAnswer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        EditTextAnswer.setText(CursorAnswer);
                        gotAnswer = true;
                        break;
                    } else if (CursorAnswer.equals("Choose #1")) {
                        EditTextAnswer.setText("Choose #1");
                        normalAnswer = true;
                        //break;
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Answer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        newAnswer = true;
                        break;
                    }

                } while (rs.moveToNext());
            }


            if (gotAnswer) {
                String Editable = EditTextAnswer.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Editable, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mydb.UpdateDummy(mydb, mGetSpinner, Editable);
                gotAnswer = false;
            }
            if (normalAnswer) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Normal Answer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mydb.UpdateDummy(mydb, mGetSpinner, "Choose #1");
                normalAnswer = false;
            }
            if (newAnswer) {
                String Editable = EditTextAnswer.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Editable, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mydb.UpdateDummy(mydb, mGetSpinner, Editable);
                newAnswer = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: cant get EditTextAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAnswer); Where is declared that EditTextAnswer  is EditText? Why is not  it final?

Comment: @DEADMC its like this sir EditText EditTextAnswer = (EditText) findView...but i already declared EditTextAnswer on the top of my onCreate()